# Data loss for real-time data table to history-data table

Tags: oracle, jsp, oracle11g, storage, real-time

Real-time data and historical data were shown for a monitoring project based on web. There are nearly 16 sensors with the sample frequency 50Hz. All the raw data of sensor must be stored into the database, which reaches nearly 900 data per second. And the data must be saved for at least three years. The database is oracle 11g.

My job is to design the database structure for the engineer of the sensor hardware company, who will write the data collecting program and store the data into database.

A real-time data table and history-data table is designed. The real-time data is read from real-time data table and history-data is read from the history-data table.

Real-data table is as following, which only stored one minute data.

```
Create Table real_data(
record_time timestamp(3),
ac_1 Float,
ac_2 Float,
ac_3 Float,
ac_4 Float,
ac_5 Float,
ac_6 Float,
ac_7 Float,
ac_8 Float,
ac_9 Float,
ac_10 Float,
ac_11 Float,
ac_12 Float,
ac_13 Float,
ac_14 Float,
ac_15 Float,
ac_16 Float
)
Tablespace data_test;
```

The structure of history-data table is the same with real-data, which consists of the primary key and partitions

```
Create Table history_data(
record_time timestamp(3),
ac_1 Float,
ac_2 Float,
ac_3 Float,
ac_4 Float,
ac_5 Float,
ac_6 Float,
ac_7 Float,
ac_8 Float,
ac_9 Float,
ac_10 Float,
ac_11 Float,
ac_12 Float,
ac_13 Float,
ac_14 Float,
ac_15 Float,
ac_16 Float
)
Tablespace data_test
PARTITION BY RANGE(record_time)  
INTERVAL(numtodsinterval(1，'day'))  
(  
  PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2016-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))  
);  

alter table history_data add constraint RECORD_DATE primary key (RECORD_TIME);
```

The interval partition is chosen for two reasons:

1. the sql query is based on time record by the web client , such as

   Select ac_1 From ac_test
   Where record_time >= to_timestamp('2016-08-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
   And  record_time <=to_timestamp('2016-08-01 00:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
2. the interval partition is ranged from days. During the test of one day data, nearly 40 seconds was cost for 4.3 million data per day.

A job is executed to transfer the real-data to history-data table per one minute. The transfer process is done by the oracle procedure, the transferring time is recorded by the another table:real_data_top_backup_date.

```
create or replace procedure copy_to_history_test is 
d_top_backup_date  timestamp(3);
begin 

select top_backup_date into d_top_backup_date from real_data_top_backup_date;   

Insert Into history_data  Select *  From real_data where record_time <d_top_backup_date; 

delete from real_data where record_time <d_top_backup_date;  

Update real_data_top_backup_date Set top_backup_date=(d_top_backup_date+1/24/60);

commit; 

end copy_to_history_test;
```

And a simulation program is written to simulate the sensor data collecting and inserting.

```
Declare  
time_index Number;
start_time Timestamp(3);
tmp_time Timestamp(3); 
tmp_value1 Float;
tmp_value2 Float;
tmp_value3 Float;
tmp_value4 Float;
tmp_value5 Float;
tmp_value6 Float;
tmp_value7 Float;
tmp_value8 Float;
tmp_value9 Float;
tmp_value10 Float;
tmp_value11 Float;
tmp_value12 Float;
tmp_value13 Float;
tmp_value14 Float;
tmp_value15 Float;
tmp_value16 Float;


Begin

--initiaze the variable  
time_index:=0;      
 SELECT to_timestamp('2016-08-01 00:00:00:000', 'yyyy-mm-dd h24:mi:ss:ff')  Into start_time  FROM DUAL;  

      While time_index<(50*60*60*24*7)
       Loop
         -- add 20 millionseconds 
         SELECT start_time+numtodsinterval((0.02*time_index),'SECOND') Into tmp_time  FROM DUAL;
        -- dbms_output.put_line(tmp_time);
         -- create random number
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value1 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value2 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value3 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value4 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value5 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value6 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value7 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value8 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value9 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value10 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value11 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value12 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value13 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value14 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value15 from dual ;
         select dbms_random.value Into tmp_value16 from dual ;
         --dbms_output.put_line(tmp_value);

        -- Insert Into ac_data (sensor_id,data,record_time) Values(sensor_index,tmp_value,tmp_time);
        Insert Into real_data Values(tmp_time,tmp_value1,tmp_value2,tmp_value3,tmp_value4,tmp_value5,tmp_value6,tmp_value7,tmp_value8,tmp_value9,tmp_value10,tmp_value11,tmp_value12,tmp_value13,tmp_value14,tmp_value15,tmp_value16);
        if mod(time_index,50)=0 then
        commit; 
        dbms_lock.sleep(1);
        End If;

         time_index:=time_index+1;
       End Loop;

 --  dbms_output.put_line(c);
  Exception
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
    log_write('insert data failure!');
End;
```

The problem is that during the transferring data procedure nearly 0.1% amount sensor data will be lost. I think that the parallel operation of the transferring data( insert the data and delete the data) leads to the data loss.  How to deal the problem?

Also under this scenario, is the database structure feasible? Is there another better design for the database?

Comment: How dou you know that data has lost?

Comment: @EvgeniyK. i found that there are 4316850  sensor data for one day, howerver it shall consist of 432000 data.

Answer (score 0):

> "nearly 0.1% amount sensor data will be lost"

Very possible. By default Oracle uses a Read Committed isolation model at the *statement level*. The isolation level means that records added to the table by other sessions won't be included in the set of records inserted by your procedure. However, provided those other sessions have committed those rows they will be in the scope of the delete statement. This phenomenon is called 'phantom reads'.

So the key point is the insertion of records into the "real-time" table. In your test harness the inserts are committed in batches of fifty `mod(time_index,50)=0`. If that commit happens in one session while `copy_to_history_test()` is running then there is a hole into which records can tumble. Perhaps your processes will different in Production.

> "how to deal the problem?"

The standard approach to this problem is to use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level. Setting this for the session which runs `copy_to_history_test()` means that all the statements will be executed using the same state of data for the duration of the transaction. Provided records are only inserted into the real-time table this approach shouldn't give you any grief. (If other process *can* update or delete those records then you have bigger architectural problems.)

So your procedure should now look like this:

```
create or replace procedure copy_to_history_test is 
  d_top_backup_date  timestamp(3);
begin 

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; -- isolate all these statements 

    select top_backup_date into d_top_backup_date from real_data_top_backup_date
    FOR UPDATE OF top_backup_date;  -- lock the table to any other session
    Insert Into history_data  Select *  From real_data where record_time <d_top_backup_date; 
    delete from real_data where record_time <d_top_backup_date;  
    Update real_data_top_backup_date Set top_backup_date=(d_top_backup_date+1/24/60);

    commit; -- reverts the isolation level

end copy_to_history_test;
```

Note that I have also locked the `real_data_top_backup_date` table. In multi-user environments it is good practice to reserve records for update to prevent transaction failure due to clashes.

The documentation covers isolation levels in great detail. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT88969).

> "Is another better design for the database?"

Well that depends on what you're trying to achieve. What is the point of the "real-time" table. It seems you only keep records in it for a minute. So the pertinent question is, why don't you just insert into the partitioned table? What value do you get from having two tables to justify such a lot of effort?

> " If the sensor data was just only inserted into the history-data table, the real-time graphic displaying is not guarantee because retrieving the data will become more slowly with the data table grows."

Have you done any benchmarks to prove that? Selecting one minute's worth of data should be fairly stable, as you are executing an index-range scan on the primary key.

Anyway, if your heart is set on the two table structure I suggest you insert  records in both tables simultaneously, using the INSERT ALL function:

```
insert all
    into real_data values (....)
    into history_data values (....)
select ....
```

The multitable syntax requires INSERT ... SELECT structure, but we can select local variables from DUAL or whatever fits your use case. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#i2125362).

Because you already have the records in the `history_data` you can remove the transference from `copy_to_history_test()` and just do the delete from the `real_data` table.

Comment: thanks for replying. i will do some test according your suggestion.

Comment: The reason for designing two tables (real_data and history_data table) is that the web clients must show the real-time data graphic per second and query the history data through the database. If the sensor data was just only inserted into the history-data table, the real-time graphic displaying is not guarantee because retrieving the data will become more slowly with the data table grows. So two table structures are designed. The real-time table only contains one minute data, nearly 54000 data. So retrieving the real-time data can be guarantee.

Comment: Thanks you very much!  I did not test the retrieving data time for just only inserting into one table. I think the inserting data will become slowly for the index exist in the table, so that the retrieving data will become slowly.  And I will try it.  Furthermore , thanks for the insert all function for this scenario.